# Menu Style CSS Java

Tags: java, css, javafx, menubar

Am hoping someone can advise what is need to be changed to remove the hideous border (?) from this menu (see image).

Have extracted modena from the java jar to see how they do it but to no avail. Sure it's very very simple just drawing a blank at the moment.

[image: Screenshot of Menu with white border on menu]

The css at the moment is very simple just not sure which element need to be changed / added.

```
    .menu-bar {
      -fx-background-color:#237a72;
      /*-fx-border-width:2;*/
    }

    .menu-bar .label {
       -fx-text-fill:#ffffff;
    }

    .menu-bar .label:hover {
       -fx-text-fill:yellow;
    }

    .menu-item {
       -fx-background-color:#237a72;
       -fx-border-color: #237a72;
    }
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white border is the background color of the context-menu.
So if you want to get rid of it, you could remove the padding:

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, was playing with the context menu at one point but didn't try padding.